# Парсинг json'а в script теге в html на nodejs

Tags: node.js

Есть сайт, например, example.com. На нем есть встроенный json таким образом:

```
<script type="application/json" id="application-locale-messages"> {тут json} </script>
```

Как мне на nodejs лучше всего получать этот json? Конкретных примеров у меня нагуглить не получилось =( Видел упоминания пары библиотек (html-to-json, osmosis), но в их документации своего случая не нашел.

Comment: библиотекой нельзя воспользоваться ?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете, например, воспользоваться одной из библиотек для парсинга html, например `fast-html-parser`:

```js
const HTMLParser = require("fast-html-parser")

let html = ....

let root = HTMLParser.parse(html, {script: true})

console.log(root.querySelector('#application-locale-messages').rawText)
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет, в итоге использовал библиотеку, правда, другую. `https://github.com/matthewmueller/x-ray` Очень легкое использование:

`var Xray = require('x-ray')
var x = Xray()
x('example.com', '#application-locale-messages')(function(err, title) {
  console.log(title)
})`